# Dividing words into 2 parts: letters and numbers

Tags: php, regex

there are strings:

```
$string1 = "text3256";
$string2 = "23PT";
```

I would like to somehow check if the word belongs to pattern "NumberText" or "TextNumber" for the purpose of splitting word into 2 parts: a "Number" and a "Text"

In the example above - words shall be divided into following:

```
"text3256" -> "text" and "3256"
"23PT" -> "23" and "PT"
```

Is it possible to create such Regex pattern? (words such as "text32text" or "44fd675" shall not be divided)..

I can most certainly create a hardcode solution using the "each character iteration" approach and checking if next character is a letter or a numeric.. that's a hardcore, so, I wondered if someone could help me out with a better, easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
'/^(?:(?:([a-z]+)(\d+))|(?:(\d+)([a-z]+)))$/i'
```

Comment: This seems to have a problem with words in the format `WordNumberWord` such as `foo123bar` matching `foo123`. You can see the result here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/vHY28F

Comment: But didn't OP write: `words such as "text32text" or "44fd675" shall not be divided)`

Comment: Yes, but you are dividing. `foo123bar` is matched as `foo`, `123`. Problem is that your regex is matching `^(?:([a-z]+)(\d+))` or `(?:(\d+)([a-z]+))$`. The anchors are included with each side of the or (`|`). So you match (the start followed by number then letters) or (letters followed by numbers and then the end). You should put parenthesis around your pattern inside the start/end anchors like `^((?:([a-z]+)(\d+))|(?:(\d+)([a-z]+)))$`. @AmalMurali also has the same problem.

Comment: Ah thanks so much, good point, that was silly mistake on my part, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using boundaries:

```
/\b((\d+)([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)(\d+))\b/i
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8muVjE